# How to get selected day/month and year from jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, uidatepicker

I am using the Jquery UI Datepicker plugin, I am trying to get the selected day, month and year from the datepicker in different variables (final solution is to assign all 3 variables to hidden fields).

Here is the code:

```
        $(function() {
        $("#_StartDate").datepicker(
            {
                 onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                    var startDate = new Date(dateText);
                    var selDay = startDate.getDay();
                    alert(selDay);
                 }
            }
        );
    });
```

I selected the date "1/10/2011" and it returns "1". I selected the date "1/25/2011" and it returns "2". What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what format jquery is returning the date in datetext variable? That might be throwing off Date object.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

getDay return the day of the week :)

You can use:

**getFullYear** for the year
**getDate** the day of the month
**getMonth** the month of the year

Follows a complete list of the getters (from [DevDocs](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/date/prototype#Methods)):

**Date.prototype.getDate()** Returns the day of the month (1-31) for the specified date according to local time.
**Date.prototype.getDay()** Returns the day of the week (0-6) for the specified date according to local time.
**Date.prototype.getFullYear()** Returns the year (4 digits for 4-digit years) of the specified date according to local time.
**Date.prototype.getHours()** Returns the hour (0-23) in the specified date according to local time.
**Date.prototype.getMilliseconds()** Returns the milliseconds (0-999) in the specified date according to local time.
**Date.prototype.getMinutes()** Returns the minutes (0-59) in the specified date according to local time.
**Date.prototype.getMonth()** Returns the month (0-11) in the specified date according to local time.
**Date.prototype.getSeconds()** Returns the seconds (0-59) in the specified date according to local time.
**Date.prototype.getTime()** Returns the numeric value of the specified date as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC (negative for prior times).
**Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()** Returns the time-zone offset in minutes for the current locale.
**Date.prototype.getUTCDate()** Returns the day (date) of the month (1-31) in the specified date according to universal time.
**Date.prototype.getUTCDay()** Returns the day of the week (0-6) in the specified date according to universal time.
**Date.prototype.getUTCFullYear()** Returns the year (4 digits for 4-digit years) in the specified date according to universal time.
**Date.prototype.getUTCHours()** Returns the hours (0-23) in the specified date according to universal time.
**Date.prototype.getUTCMilliseconds()** Returns the milliseconds (0-999) in the specified date according to universal time.
**Date.prototype.getUTCMinutes()** Returns the minutes (0-59) in the specified date according to universal time.
**Date.prototype.getUTCMonth()** Returns the month (0-11) in the specified date according to universal time.
**Date.prototype.getUTCSeconds()** Returns the seconds (0-59) in the specified date according to universal time.
**Date.prototype.getYear()** Returns the year (usually 2-3 digits) in the specified date according to local time. Use getFullYear()** instead.

Answer (score 3):

Its only returning `.getDay()` (day of the week 0-6), you need to do something like:

```
var selDay = ...
var selMon = startDate.getMonth();
var selYear = startDate.getYear();
```

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

**NOTE**

Pay special attention to what is returned, getDay() -> 0-6
getMonth() -> 0-11, etc... all in the reference I provided.

Answer (score 0):

To grab val from input field:

```
var start_date=$('input#start_date').val();
```